# calling loc with a boolean array containing NA

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The pandas doc on loc states that it can be used with boolean arrays, more specifically it states the following:

*"Allowed inputs are: ... A boolean array (any `NA` values will be treated as `False`)."*

My question: How can u create a boolean array containing NA-values? I mean: A numpy bool array can't contain Nans and if we interpret this more liberal as stating "a list containing boolean values and na" then loc throws exceptions, e.g.:

```
d_test = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1,2,3,5], "q1": [1,4,4,2], "q2": [4,np.nan,9,0]}, index=["a","b","c","d"])
t1 = [True,False,False,np.nan]
d_test.loc[t1] # KeyError
#same with None:
t1 = [True,False,False,None]
```

So my question: How is this sentence to be interpreted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think they mean a [BooleanArray](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.arrays.BooleanArray.html) (*which can be created with* [`pd.array`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.array.html#pandas.array)) :

> Array of **boolean** (`True`/`False`) data **with missing values**.

```
t1 = [True,False,False,np.nan]

out = d_test.loc[pd.array(t1, dtype="boolean")]
```

So, since `np.nan` is treated as `False`, only the first row is being selected by the mask.

Output :

```
print(out)

   id  q1   q2
a   1   1 4.00
```

Comment: Thanks! So but this is an extension type of pandas - correct?

Comment: Yes but to be specific, that’s a pandas extension array.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @Timeless's answer. If you convert your list as `Index` or `Series` the default type will be inferred by Pandas:

```
>>> help(pd.Index)

...
 |  dtype : NumPy dtype (default: object)
 |      If dtype is None, we find the dtype that best fits the data.
 |      If an actual dtype is provided, we coerce to that dtype if it's safe.
 |      Otherwise, an error will be raised.
...
```

In your case, `t1` will be an object:

```
>>> pd.Index(t1)
Index([True, False, False, nan], dtype='object')
```

If you force the `dtype` as `boolean`:

```
>>> pd.Index(t1, dtype='boolean')  # From pd.BooleanDtype()
Index([True, False, False, <NA>], dtype='boolean')
```

Take care about the difference between `boolean` and `bool`, the result is not the same!

```
>>> pd.Index(t1, dtype='bool')
Index([True, False, False, True], dtype='bool')
```

Only the boolean form (whatever if the dtype is `bool` or `boolean`) is allowed to mask your dataframe:

```
>>> d_test.loc[pd.Index(t1, dtype='boolean')]  # what you want
   id  q1   q2
a   1   1  4.0

>>> d_test.loc[pd.Index(t1, dtype='bool')]  # what you don't want
   id  q1   q2
a   1   1  4.0
d   5   2  0.0
```